# Why are my beans disabled onStartUp after upgrading to grails5?

Tags: spring-boot, grails, spring-security

I am upgrading my Grails 3 app to Grails 5 and during start up i see the following logs

```
2024-02-23 11:08:29.189  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter securityRequestHolderFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:30.008  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter securityContextPersistenceFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:30.465  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter mutableLogoutFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:31.069  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter casAuthenticationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:31.268  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter grailsUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:31.577  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter restAuthenticationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:32.693  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:33.077  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter grailsRememberMeAuthenticationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:38.325  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter grailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:08:40.264  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter restTokenValidationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:12:44.021  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter formContentFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:12:44.023  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter exceptionTranslationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:12:44.029  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter updateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:12:44.029  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter filterSecurityInterceptor was not registered (disabled)
2024-02-23 11:12:44.029  INFO 70553 --- [           main] o.s.boot.web.servlet.RegistrationBean    : Filter switchUserFilter was not registered (disabled)
```